# Parsing information between pages in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, handler

What I want to happen is when the user chooses the amount they want they click on submit. Now that amount will be passed on to the next page.

The problem is I dont understand the code in the handler, does any know a simple bit of code i can get to make this happen?

Sorry but I am not clear with asp and asp.net

Thanks

```
<form id='sampleform' method='post' action='handler.asp' >
   <p>
   Name: <input type='text' name='Name' />
   </p>
   <p>
   Email: <input type='text' name='Email' />
   </p>
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="ten" /> &pound;10
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="five" /> &pound;5
<input type="radio" name="subject" value="three" /> &pound;3
&pound;<input type='text' name='donate-amount' />
   <p>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
   </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if I could see the code in handler.asp. Try the following as your handler.asp page

```
<%=Request.Form("Name")%> <br />
<%=Request.Form("Email")%> <br />
<%=Request.Form("subject")%> <br />
<%=Request.Form("donate-amount")%> <br />
```